# Simplest way to return data from line in file

Tags: bash

I have a file `tmp.info` that is formatted like so:

```
foo..............bar
alligator........bear
cat..............dog
```

and I would like to make a small wrapper command in bash that returns the second string in the line when the first is supplied to the function. For example, something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

get_from_info_file() {
cat $1 | grep $2 | grep ????????
}

echo `get_from_info_file tmp.info alligator`
```

should return:

```
>>> bear
```

What is the most elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use awk, like this:

```
get_info_from_file() {
    awk -F'\\.+' -v search="$2" '$1 == search { print $2 }' "$1"
}
```

This sets the field separator to one or more `.`s and sets the variable `search`, using the second argument passed to the function. If the first field `$1` is equal to the search string, print the second field.

Testing it out, using the file in your question:

```
$ get_info_from_file tmp.info alligator
bear
```

Comment: Good answer in that it only uses one executable (awk)

Answer (score 3):

Declare your function as this:

```
#!/bin/bash

get_from_info_file() {
    sed -n "s/$2\.*\(.*\)/\1/p" "$1"
}
```

Call it with `filename` as the first paramater and the searched key as the second parameter:

```
echo `get_from_info_file tmp.info alligator`
```

Prints:

```
bear
```

Answer (score 1):

This function implements what you need:

```
function getValue(){
     local value=$1
     local file=$2
     grep ^$value\. $file | tr -s '.' | cut -d'.' -f2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A (not elegant) bash only version:

```
#!/bin/bash
get_from_info_file() {
  file=$(<$1)
  i1=${file##*$2}
  i2=${i1%%[:punct:]*}
  echo ${i2##*\.}
}

echo `get_from_info_file tmp.info alligator`
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is:

```
line=$(cat $1 | grep $2) 
array=(${line//./ } ) 
echo ${array[1]}
```

1. grep the line and store it in variable
2. use the variable substitution replace '.' to space, wrap it in array
3. print the second item of the array

Answer (score 0):

using `grep` (notice to `\K`):

```
get_from_info_file() {
    grep -Po "$2\.+\K\w+" "$1"
}
```

usig `perl`:

```
get_from_info_file() {
    perl -nle 'print $1 if /'"$2"'\.*(.*)/' "$1"
}
```

using `expr` matching operator `:` :

```
get_from_info_file() {
    a=$(grep "$2" "$1")
    expr "$a" : "^\.*\(.[a-z]*\)"
}
```

using `sed`:

```
get_from_info_file() {
    grep "$2" "$1" | sed -r 's|.*\.+(.*)|\1|'
}
```